# Why can't a template function resolve a pointer to a derived class to be a pointer to a base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, pointers, template-function

**Is the compiler unable, at compile-time, to take a pointer to a derived class and know that it has a base class?** It seems like it can't, based on the following test. See my comment at the end for where the issue occurs.

**How can I get this to work?**

```
std::string nonSpecStr = "non specialized func";
std::string const specStr = "specialized func";
std::string const nonTemplateStr = "non template func";

class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};
class OtherClass {};


template <typename T> std::string func(T * i_obj)
{ return nonSpecStr; }

template <> std::string func<Base>(Base * i_obj)
{ return specStr; }

std::string func(Base * i_obj)
{ return nonTemplateStr; }

class TemplateFunctionResolutionTest
{
public:
    void run()
    {
        // Function resolution order
        // 1. non-template functions
        // 2. specialized template functions
        // 3. template functions
        Base * base = new Base;
        assert(nonTemplateStr == func(base));

        Base * derived = new Derived;
        assert(nonTemplateStr == func(derived));

        OtherClass * otherClass = new OtherClass;
        assert(nonSpecStr == func(otherClass));


        // Why doesn't this resolve to the non-template function?
        Derived * derivedD = new Derived;
        assert(nonSpecStr == func(derivedD));
    }
};
```

Comment: I think that what you want to achieve is not a good programming style. You are using too subtile aspects of the language. App code should not be a compiler test. Prætorian is saying a right thing, but will that work for all compilers?

Comment: @KirillKobelev Overload resolution is a sequence of well-defined steps. Any compiler that behaves differently would be non-conforming.

Comment: @KirillKobelev This is really very basic stuff. Any compiler not even getting this one right would usable, even for simple programs.

Comment: "`template <> std::string func<Base>`" why are you trying to write template function specialisations? They have a few very specific uses, and this is not one of these.

Comment: @curiousguy The question is simple because I want it to be clear and  easily answered, without a bunch of extraneous details. My actual need for template specialization, overloading functions, etc, is a bit more complicated than the question is able to show.

Comment: @ChrisMorris OK. Still, **be careful with specialisation of overloaded function templates**, this is almost always a bad idea; IMO the use of explicitly specialised function templates should be restricted to functions that **cannot be overloaded**, f.ex. `template <typename T> T read(istream&); template <> int read<int>(istream&);`

Comment: @curiousguy In my case, if I didn't use templates, I'd have to define an ever-growing number of functions. Given the fact that almost every function would be defined the same, my code is a prime candidate for templating.

Comment: @ChrisMorris I get the point of template, and of parametrized generic programming in general. What is not clear is why you would want to use **explicit function template specialisation** here.

Comment: @curiousguy I was doing it because one type needed to have a different implementation than the rest. And I was not using type traits. I am probably going to switch over to type traits, which will probably remove the need for the explicit specialization for a particular type.

Comment: @ChrisMorris "_I was doing it because one type needed to have a different implementation than the rest._" but why a **template function specialisation**? You do **not** need one here.

Comment: @curiousguy Maybe I don't understand the question. I needed to specialize the template function for a specific type. The question I posted does not show this because I am simplifying my question so it is easier to answer and so unnecessary details don't get in the way. In other words, the actual problem that I posted is just a proof-of-concept, to show the problem that I was running into on my more complicated, real code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15287/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-chris-morris)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Derived * derivedD = new Derived;
assert(nonSpecStr == func(derivedD));
```

This doesn't resolve to the non-template function as you expect it to because to do that a cast from `Derived *` to `Base *` must be performed; but this cast is not needed for the template version, which results in the latter being a better match during overload resolution.

To force the template function to not match both `Base` and `Derived` you can use SFINAE to reject both those types.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};
class OtherClass {};

template <typename T> 
typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_base_of<Base,T>::value,std::string
  >::type
  func(T *)
{ return "template function"; }

std::string func(Base *)
{ return "non template function"; }

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<Base> p1( new Base );
  std::cout << func(p1.get()) << std::endl;

  std::unique_ptr<Derived> p2( new Derived );
  std::cout << func(p2.get()) << std::endl;

  std::unique_ptr<Base> p3( new Derived );
  std::cout << func(p3.get()) << std::endl;

  std::unique_ptr<OtherClass> p4( new OtherClass );
  std::cout << func(p4.get()) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
non template function
non template function
non template function
template function
```

Comment: Is there a way to put a restriction on the generic template function, something to specify that the template argument only applies to objects that are numeric, for instance? If I could do this, then Derived * wouldn't resolve to the generic template function because it is not numeric, and thus would resolve to the function I want it to. Could type traits help with this?

Comment: "_to do that a cast_" a **conversion**

Comment: @Prætorian Unfortunately, my compiler does not support the enable_if or unique_ptr directives. I've got another question that piggybacks off of this one at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938359/why-doesnt-my-function-skip-trying-to-resolve-to-the-incompatible-template-func

Comment: @ChrisMorris `enable_if` is trivial to create on your own, [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) shows a possible implementation. As for `unique_ptr` it wasn't really pertinent to your question, I was only using it to avoid having to `delete` the objects.

Comment: @Prætorian Yeah, I think I'm going to make some custom type trait to deal with my issue. Thanks.